# Count No of Follower on Instagram ? any Permanent solution?

Tags: web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to pull the number of followers from a list of Instagram accounts.

I want to integrate Instagram API or any hack solution to get out no of followers on the Instagram account.

I found many solutions for the above problem but none of them work properly

the link which I follow:
[Grab Instagram Follower count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822860/grab-instagram-follower-count)
[Grab Instagram Follower count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822860/grab-instagram-follower-count)

Comment: I tried your first link, and the proposed solution works perfectly to retrieve followers/followed with this url: https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1

Comment: @AnotherOne I tried this one not working always,

Comment: this works fine in postman or any browser, but when I am trying to write script in python getting None in response

Comment: This is maybe due to instagram trying to prevent you from accessing this data programmatically. You could try to fool their server by copying the request headers of Postman or your Browser in your code before making a request.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Instagram doesn't have any APIs official or unofficial.

So, I have used the Node.Js and implemented this by following the [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-count-of-instagram-followers-using-node-js/) code

**Index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const followers = require('instagram-followers');
const app = express();
    
app.get('/' , (req , res)=>{
    res.send("GeeksforGeeks");
});
    
app.get('/:username' , (req , res) => {
    followers(req.params.username).then((count) => {
        if(!count){
            res.send("Account Not Found");
            return;
        }
        res.send("Username " + req.params.username +
            " have " + "<b>" + count + "</b>" + " followers");

    });
});

// Server setup
app.listen(4000 , ()=>{
    console.log("server is running on port 4000");
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could use a ajax request for getting the count by using this [link](https://support.pixelunion.net/hc/en-us/articles/360041460554-Important-notice-Instagram-feed-removal) to get token

```
  $.ajax({

  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self',

  dataType: 'jsonp',

  type: 'GET',

  data: {access_token: token},

  success: function(data){

      var follows = data['data']['counts']['follows'];

      $(".instagram").text(follows);

  },

  error: function(data){

      console.log(data);

  }
```

if you need more information you can check the [source](https://onlinecode.org/how-to-get-instagram-followers-count-using-jquery-ajax/) from where i found it

Answer (score 1):

[Github Link for Instagram Unofficial API](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api) Check out the API and follow the steps as I am showing you.

## Install the API

`pip install git+https://git@github.com/ping/instagram_private_api.git@1.6.0`

## Code

```py
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch 
username = 'test' 
password = 'test' 
api = Client(username, password) 
results = api.user_follows('test') 
print([item['pk'] for item in results.get('users', [])])
```

Comment: getting this error AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'user_follows'

Comment: i am sure if i used this package rate limit will come into picture because of login(user level ratelimit)